# I am not able to select option value from drop down list .select tag not containing any id or class or name

Tags: selenium

I am not able to select option value from drop down list .select tag not containing any id or class or name.

```
 <select>
 <option title="Select" value="">Select</option>
 <option title="Packages" value="PK" maxCount="1" cgCount="0">Packages</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: what about its parent? does it have an id, class name or any other attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Use this, mine works :):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"));
    Select dropdown = new Select(element);
    dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Source: [Sumit Mittal Blog](http://sumitbit2005.blogspot.in/2014/01/working-with-dropdown-using-selenium.html)

Comment: can you pls tell me ,how to give input ?

Comment: Use: dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Packages");

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));
Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<select id="designation">
<option value="MD">MD</option>
<option value="prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value="CEO"> CEO </option>
</select>
```

Below is the drop down :)

Now to identify dropdown do

1

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
```

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do 
?
1

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");
```

or 
?
1

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

or 
?
1

```
dropdown.selectByValue("prog");
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer");
```